# Remove background from webcam in windows

Tags: windows, gratis, webcam

Is there a free software to remove background from live webcam video in Windows?

Requirements:

- Remove background from live webcam video
- Without the need for a green screen

OS: Windows. License: Gratis

Comment: Are you using a "green screen"?

Comment: @MrWhite No, I'm not using a green screen. Thanks, I edited the question.

Comment: I'd say it's near impossible and that's why we *do use greenscreens*. [A recent feature of Skype](https://blogs.skype.com/news/2019/02/06/introducing-background-blur-in-skype/) is being able to blur your background however, so there might be hope.